# C++ : restrict access to the superclass' methods selectively?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is an interview question. I am not a C++ expert yet so i need some help in finding the answer to this question ( i first want to understand the question...is it a valid question?)

Question:

> Suppose I have a class B that derives
>   from class A and I wanted to reuse
>   some, but not all of the methods of A.
>   How would I restrict access to the
>   superclass' methods selectively?

thanks!

Comment: You probably mean you *want to reuse some ... of the methods of **A***.

Comment: yes.. I've made the correction..thanks..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that

1. you cannot change the definition of `A`
2. you want to select which methods from `A` should be accessible from a `B` object.

The `using` directive solves your problem. Example:

```
class A
{
public: // or protected for that matter
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

class B : private A // or protected, depending on whether
                    // you want subclasses of B to expose
                    // some methods from A themselves
{
public:
    using A::foo;
};
```

makes `foo` usable from class `B`, but not `bar`. But as a caveat, note that `using A::foo` will expose all overloads of `foo`.

Comment: This is a good solution, fulfilling the question given. However, it should be noted that class B is completely apart from the inheritance hierarchy, so it is not possible to do something like "B objB; A* ptrA = &objB;". AFAIK, there is no completely satisfying solution for this question.

Comment: @Baltasarq: what is the point of restricting methods of `A` if you can access them through a bare pointer to `A` ? Recall that private inheritance is **not** a "is a" relationship. It is only remotely related to "normal" public inheritance, and should be viewed as a composition device.

Comment: can you explain "But as a caveat, note that using A::foo will expose all overloads of foo" ?

Comment: @maxpayne: if you have multiple `foo` methods with different signatures, you either expose them as a bunch or not at all.

Comment: @maxpayne: as a workaround for the caveat, you can always provide a specific subset of functions in the derived class that simply call into the base class to do the work - a little more verbose but giving better control.

Comment: @Baltasarq: excellent point to raise, although it's important to preserve the Liskov Substitution Principal in handling derived classes via base class pointers, so "there is no completely satisfying solution" applies to the problem, not some limitation of C++.

Comment: @Tony: Indeed, but in case the base class function is virtual, a client inheriting the derived class must be told to override the *base class* method, which could be difficult to document.

Comment: @Tony: there is indeed no LSP with private inheritance. Since you don't want to expose the whole `A` interface, there is no point in allowing a cast to `A`, and therefore no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @Tony, @Alexandre, taking into account all caveats, I'd then prefer to wrap the class in an adapter. I know that the question, as asked, do not allow that solution, but I think it is the preferred approach. @Tony, Eiffel does allow to rename methods on inheritance. Also, mixins are recognized uses of inheritance that do not match the Liskov substitution.

Answer (score 3):

The answer they probably want to hear is that you can put the methods to be reused in the `protected` section of the base class, the methods which should not be visible to the derived classes should go into the `private` section.

However, taking a step back, you might be able to score extra points by pointing out that there might be better measures for reusing code, depending on what the functions do (such as using free functions which are not visible in a header file).

Comment: @maxpayne: plain vanilla functions, ie. functions which are not member functions ("methods")

Comment: while your solution is really simple and clean...i think it will not hold if one is not allowed to change the code in class A..